# Точная разница между понятиями "свобода" и "воля"

Tags: значение-слов

В русском языке есть два слова, обозначающих примерно одно и то же - свобода и воля. Одно и то же, да не одно. Все-таки оттенками эти понятия различаются.
Но я это интуитивно чувствую, однако словами выразить различия никак не могу. Помогите, пожалуйста, так сказать, вербально выразить разницу между понятиями "свобода" и "воля".
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: «Точная разница в оттенках» вербальная по форме? — Тютелька.

Answer (score 5):

В современном языке эти слова не совпадают по области значений и ситуациям употребления.

1."Свобода", в отличие от "воли", не употребляется в значении "желание".

2."Свобода" в современном формальном значении противоположности насильственному удержанию где-либо применяется к людям, к животным применяется "воля".

В бытовой речи "воля" в данном значении вполне может заменять "свободу", как исторический синоним этого слова (в уголовном жаргоне это практически перевод слова "свобода").

3."Воля" в современном формальном смысле (политика, выборы, нотариальное дело) всегда означает "выраженное желание".

4."Свобода" и производные понятия (степени свободы, свободный электрон и т.п.) применяется в технической терминологии по отношению к неодушевлённым сущностям, "воля" - нет.

Answer (score 3):

Если совсем кратко: свобода — это состояние, воля — это способность. 
Если расписать, то свобода —  это отсутствие всякого рода ограничений (например, свобода выбора, свобода от тюрьмы и т.д.). Воля — это качество (воля к победе, воля для совершения какого-либо действия). В таких контекстах эти слова не могут заменять друг друга. Существуют лишь редкие исключения, когда свобода и воля выступают синонимами, например: вышел на волю/свободу, но в большинстве случаев, эти слова подчиняются вышеизложенным характеристикам.

Answer (score 3):

Свобода и воля - эти слова в др.-русском языке известны с XI в., и тогда они были очень близки по смыслу. Свобода - от "свой, собственный", воля - от "велеть, желать". Тогда СВОБОДА - ЭТО "СВОЯ" ВОЛЯ (современное "своеволие", но без отрицательной оценки), свободный - имеющий возможность проявить свою волю, осуществить желание.

Исходное значение прилагательного "вольный" - действующий по своей воле, свободный, а "волевой" - очень позднее образование, оно соответствует основному современному значению слова "воля" (способность человека управлять собой, своими действиями).

Но со временем значения слов разошлись, и только в четвертой-пятой словарной статье совпадают как "отсутствие зависимости от кого-л., возможность располагать собою по собственному усмотрению" и "возможность действовать в какой-л. области без ограничений, запретов, беспрепятственно".

Comment: Думаю что слово "волевой" из политической риторики (волевое решение, волевые усилия, волевая личность и др.), по своему значению связано не напрямую со словом "воля" (желание), а с ранее образованным понятием "сила воли" (сильное желание, приводящее к настойчивым действиям и т.п.). "Волевой человек" обладает "силой воли" - либо для решения сложных проблем, либо для подавления ("пересиливания") воли других.

Comment: Волевые усилия - проявления настойчивости, основанные на силе воли. Волевое решение - дипломатичное наименование решения, навязанного силой - вопреки воле несогласных (сломить волю других). Просто "волю" (желание) можно высказать, изъявить при голосовании, сообщить в завещании и т.п. "Силу воли" можно проявить только ("волевым") действием.